# How to use rotation in iOS 8

Tags: ios, rotation, ios8

What I want to do is, that after the device is rotated, the UI needs to get changed.

This is what I tried:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
 {
     UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
     if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
         if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
             _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20.0,850.0,728,90 )];}
         if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
             _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-10,615.0,728,90 )];}
         if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
             _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-10,615.0,728,90 )];}}

 } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
 {    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20.0,850.0,728,90 )];}
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-10,615.0,728,90 )];}
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-10,615.0,728,90 )];}}


 }];

[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

I don´t really know, how to do this the right way, so maybe you guys can tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, last answer was wrong...

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [self positionViews]; // set the new frames in here.
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) { }];
}
```

Comment: ok, should have cleared first, your solution worked, thx a lot :)